# How to compile android goldfish 3.4 kernel on 32-bit linux

Tags: android, linux

First let me tell you that I am working on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 32-bit. I am trying to compile Goldfish 3.4 kernel. I downloaded a prebuilt gcc from:

```
git clone https://android.googlesource.com/platform/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-eabi-4.6
```

However, I found that it doesn't work because it's 64-bit ELF file. Where can I find a 32-bit arm-eabi-gcc?

Answer (score 0):

***You need to set 'ARCH' explicitly to 'arm'***

I used to compile a goldfish kernel 3.4 on 32-bit Linux using the following steps:

> *git clone* https://android.googlesource.com/platform/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-eabi-4.8

Add **bin** directory to your PATH variable, since it contains the required compiler and linker

> *export ARCH=arm*
>
> *export SUBARCH=arm*
>
> *export CROSS_COMPILE=arm-eabi-*
>
> *make goldfish_armv7_defconfig*
>
> *make -j4*

After a successful compilation, the kernel image can be found under:

> $KERNEL_SRC/arch/arm/boot/**zImage**